# javascript error "invalid XML attribute value <script language=JavaScript>\n"

Tags: javascript

i have some `javascript` files included in my html file for months. It used to work just fine until couple of days ago, now my scripts don't run anymore and i get `javascript error "invalid XML attribute value <script language=JavaScript>\n"` with firebug.

Does anyone know what this error means and how to get rid of it? i guess is something about that `newline` "\n" but i can't see that in my file if i open it.

Comment: now it's <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, `language` was never part of any specification, at least not in XHTML (And I think not in HTML, either.)

Try whether `<script type="text/javascript">` works better.

Comment: ok...now my line looks like this <script src="javascript/jquery.imageoverlay.js" type="text/javascript"></script>, and curiously i get same error ...

Comment: It used to be!, was deprecated in HTML 4: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html

Comment: @Nick Cheers for the info! @kmunky strange. Can you run your page(s) through a validator?

Comment: omg...i can't get it work! @Pekka i've read that article, i have changed the doctype,i've included my scripts just like there....and...still same problem..

Comment: @kmunky can you post the HTML before and after the script part please?

Comment: actually i solved the problem. Weird, i found some "foreign" code in my .js files(at the bottom of my code) that started with "<script type=text/javascript>". How could that happen? maybe a virus on the server?

Comment: i have no freakin' idea :D it looks something like some variables with some encoded values, nothing readable

Comment: I have the same problem with a JSONP application. Really, can`t solve it :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to find that `<script language=JavaScript>` and replace with

```
<script language="JavaScript">
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of missing quotes on `language=JavaScript`, but as the other answers say, it's best to replace it with `type="text/javascript"` (including the quotes!)

Make sure to *always* put your attributes in quotes, in this case you would have gotten another validation error even after doing so, but in itself is still a validation error, more importantly, it's a validation error with very real side-effects in many cases.